# loop the pycountry convert

Tags: python

def country_to_continent(country_name):
    country_alpha2 = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(country_name)
    country_continent_code = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_alpha2)
    country_continent_name = pc.convert_continent_code_to_continent_name(country_continent_code)
    return country_name

country_name = [i for i in df['country']]
country_to_continent(country_name)

this is my code and I want to loop my df['country'] and get the continent name but it has error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

my purpose is to convert a country to the continent and to calculate every sum of continent's suicides cases

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my entire error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-197-3be113b9bda3> in <module>
      6 
      7 country_name = [i for i in df['country']]
----> 8 country_to_continent(country_name)

<ipython-input-197-3be113b9bda3> in country_to_continent(country_name)
      1 def country_to_continent(country_name):
----> 2     country_alpha2 = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(country_name)
      3     country_continent_code = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_alpha2)
      4     country_continent_name = pc.convert_continent_code_to_continent_name(country_continent_code)
      5     return country_name
```

D:\pythin\lib\site-packages\pycountry_convert\convert_countries.py in country_name_to_country_alpha2(cn_name, cn_name_format)

```
    68         return cn_name
     69 
---> 70     if cn_name not in dict_country_name_to_country_alpha2:
     71         raise KeyError("Invalid Country Name: '{0}'".format(cn_name))
     72 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: where is df defined?

Comment: my df is my data frame. and I define it at the beginning/ df = pd.read_csv('master.csv')